# One common dialog for different types of input data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following interfaces describing different types of persons in the system:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
  // and many other common fields
}

interface Client extends Person {
  diagnose: string;
}

interface Specialist extends Person {
  isAvailable: boolean;
  speciality: string;
}
```

I need to create a dialog for creating/editing those persons.
Is there any pattern to create one common dialog for this purpose where I can pass typed props (Client or Specialist) and edit specific fields of each as well?
I tried to use generic component with generic props however I am stuck with specific fields editing anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: is there ever a case when you will have a person who is not a client or a specialist?

Comment: No, there are only two types

Comment: have you tried the union type Specialist & Client

Comment: This is the same as creating a big common prop type which includes all the fields from both Client and Specialist and pass it to the Component. I am trying to find a way to use strongly typed props, either Client or Specialist. Is it possible?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to type as either client or specialist but negate a blend of both. Correct...?

Comment: Correct. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out by using union type with discriminator field:

```
enum PersonType {
  Client = "client",
  Specialist = "specialist"
}

interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
  type: PersonType;
  // and many other common fields
}

interface Client extends Person {
  type: PersonType.Client;
  diagnose: string;  
}

interface Specialist extends Person {
  type: PersonType.Specialist;
  isAvailable: boolean;
  speciality: string;
}
```